# jQuery how to determine value of select on document load

Tags: jquery

How can I determine the initial value of a select item?

This does not seem to work...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if( $(".c5sliderSelect option:selected").val()==''){
        //do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var selectedValue = $(".c5sliderSelect option:selected").val();
});
```

Edit: Missread, this should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.val()` directly on the select box is fine enough to retrieve it's currently selected value.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if( $(".c5sliderSelect").val()==''){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

//java script code

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var selecval = $("select option:selected").val();
alert(selecval);
```

});

see example here http://jsfiddle.net/vikastyagi87/SwWEx/2/